# HDMI to Dual Link DVI upscaler? (HDMI -> 2560x1600)

Tags: hdmi, dvi, conversion

I have a NEC 3090 screen at home, its a gorgeous 30 inch 2560x1600 monitor and I have two Dual Link DVI input on this screen...  I was considering perhaps buying a console and/or a blueray player to attach to the monitor, then I ran into the first limitation...

HDMI - Supports up to 1920x1080 The latter HDMI versions do support up to 2560x1600 but most devices does not seem to support up to this resolution, only up to 1920x1080 hence I would need some sort of up-converter.

I did a bunch of search and found a bunch of SD or 720p converter to 1920x1080 but didn't find any converter to 2560x1600...

I did find some DVI upscalers but the majority of them maxed out at 1920x1200 or so.  My NEC 3090 has no internal scaler so it *HAS* to be 2560x1600 to accept the input.

The main reason why I am looking for an upscaler is so that I don't have to buy a tv that I probably will only use to watch *some* blueray or play a couple of console games.  Plus I don't have the room for a large HDTV in my apartment anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with a simple dual-link DVI to HDMI cable or dongle?  There are plenty that carry the signal through normally (assuming the HDMI on the device supports it, of course, but you know that!)

Comment: Device support.  From what I've read, most device "claims" to have up to HDMI 1.3a but they omit to support certain features such as "over" 1920x1080p hence having a 1.3a device is worthless on 2560x1600.  Hence the upscaler.

Comment: @Pharaun OH.  You're interested in a standalone player.  I must have read the question wrong...I will agree it's probably hard as hell to find a Blu-Ray player that will output over 1920x1080 because obviously that's the native resolution of such content.  That said...are you sure this monitor won't scale to ANY other resolution?  (I found a few mentions that it would downscale to 1080p if you turn HDCP on...and I don't recall the last time I saw an LCD monitor that would ONLY DO ONE RESOLUTION PERIOD...)

Comment: Oh wow it actually does support 1080p content.  I was under the impression that it had *NO* internal scaler, some of the 30" that I've looked in didn't have one at all.  Finally dragged out the specifications and found that it was able to scale.... However looks like HDCP is only supported on the DVI-D not the DVI-I (Which would take analog/digital signal, so might need to experiment to see if it can still scale from the DVI-D input)

Comment: @Pharaun Right, HDCP isn't supported over any analog connection, period, that I'm aware of.  (Too easy to steal it!)  You should be fine running DVI-D though.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is simple. 
DVI-D 2560 with anydvd HD will enable upscale (and play in 2560).
or get a mini displayport cable, still using anydvd hd if your screen has that input.

D